# Unit testing results between several stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server

I need to unit test results between several stored procedures on a single database (certain values between different results sets ought to be the same). Also, I need to be able to copy these unit test such that several identical databases will perform the unit tests identically when I choose to start the tests.

I want to use `OpenRowSet` to dump these results to temp tables and then compare these tables, possibly using a stored procedure that I can execute once a week.

Before I configure the servers to allow this are there any reasons not to use `OpenRowSet`? If so then what other options might I have?

Comment: unclear what you mean when you say a single database contains the stored procedures but executed by several other ones. what are you using to execute the unit tests?

Comment: We have several databases that are identical. I'd like it if these databases can perform routine self-checks. Ideally I can manage a single test that several databases perform. If I had say, a stored procedure I could simply script out a `CREATE` statement and run it on all the databases so I can call it at any time that'd be a solid solution. I'm basically asking if what I'm thinking is a good way to do this or if it's too risky security-wise.

Comment: check out http://tsqlt.org/

Comment: @sarin That looks very interesting but I'm not sure if it's more favorable to OpenRowSet. Is this route more secure or more easy to maintain? The beauty of OpenRowSet for example, is that any changes to the Stored Procedures are automatically supported via a bulk insert as long as I'm not touching the name of the fields of interest.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason to not use `OpenRowSet` is that you don't need to use it. Since you want to do testing, you should use a testing framework. I am a huge fan of DbFit ( http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/ ). Your tests are completely isolated from your database. It is very easy to set up and modify. And you can even compare result sets between two Stored Procedures. It is very easy to automate. It is easy to create subsections and only run tests in a particular subsection, or an individual test. You can stage the test with DML statements and everything will get rolled back at the end of the test. You can use variables to grab data from a query or procedure and use that in calls / queries that follow.

Answer (score 1):

Well... Perhaps using a unit testing framework is a step too far for you. If you don't want to go that far, try the below.

From [MSDN OpenRowset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) "is an alternative to accessing tables in a linked server and is a one-time, ad hoc method of connecting and accessing remote data by using OLE DB". You have stated that there are several databases on the same server (i.e. no linked server). Therefore OpenRowSet seems to be overkill. You can still get the bulk performance gains by using "Select Into" statements to create your data tables in a new unit testing database (I wouldn't advokate creating test tables in your prod databases). This would have a stored proc that calls each individual database using 3 or 4 part naming. If you really wanted to you could have a table of database\stored procedures and use dynamic SQL to execute them all. once you have all the data your stored proc just needs to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

- Another way would be introduce a kind of ReturnType in your stored
  procedures, or use an existing parameter to send that value.
- When the ReturnType is set to 'INSERT_RESULTS_TO_TEST' or some such,
  then have the stored procedures' final return statements, insert
  records into test tables designed for testing, instead of their
  default return.
- If necessary, have additional columns in the test tables to indicate,
  which server, which database, which stored procedure is producing the
  result. Say call these ResultSetID.
- Then, for your comparison, use self-joins on the test tables
  comparing for the values between different ResultSetIDs.